Event study: Group periods at margins
For an event study (staggered Diff-in-Diff with different treatment periods) I would like to group the periods at the edges so that we get the coefficients for <=x / >=x , such as:

For starters, I am using the did package for the Callaway & Sant'Anna (2021) methodology. Later I will use others from the literature as well.
My approach is the following:
#Reproducible dummy dataset:

pacman::p_load("did","tidyverse")

# set seed so everything is reproducible
set.seed(1999)
sp <- reset.sim(time.periods = 13, n = 200, ipw = TRUE, reg = TRUE)


# generate dataset with 13 time periods
time.periods <- 13

# add dynamic effects
sp$te.e <- 1:time.periods

# generate data set with these parameters
dta <- build_sim_dataset(sp)


#adjustments for similarity to use case
dta <- dta %>% select(-c(X,cluster)) %>% 
  rename(startyear=G) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(treat=ifelse(period>=startyear,1,0),
         period=period-startyear) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(startyear=1997+startyear,
         year=period+startyear)

#Data Transformation for the intended analysis/graph:

dta2 <- dta %>% 
  mutate(year=ifelse(period<=-4,startyear-4,year)) %>% 
  mutate(year=ifelse(period>=4,startyear+4,year)) %>% 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  summarise(Y=mean(Y),
            startyear=first(startyear)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(period=year-startyear)


#Analysis:

mod <- did::att_gt(yname = "Y", 
                   tname = "year",
                   idname = "id",
                   gname = "startyear",
                   control_group= "notyettreated",
                   bstrap = FALSE,
                   data = dta2,
                   print_details = FALSE,
                   allow_unbalanced_panel = TRUE)

event_std <- did::aggte(mod, type = "dynamic", na.rm=TRUE)

ggdid(event_std)

Questions are:
a) Is this how you would calculate the joint coefficient for summarized periods at the edges? I am aware that I could for instance limit the shown periods within the did::aggte command with min_e / max_e, but this would just cut off my observations, not summarize them, I believe.
b) I seem to be unable to define the periods like this. The result is always such that on the right I can only show the absolute value of the lowest value minus 1. So if the lowest value were <=4, only (>=)3 would be displayed on the right-hand side. That is puzzling. Where does this come from and how can I manipulate this?
